# Secret Key - Setting environment variable PowerShell (Windows)

Tags: python, powershell, environment-variables, virtualenv

I have been attempting to clone a github repository:
https://github.com/shreyashankar/gpt3-sandbox

- Step 4 involves creating a .cfg file to add in a secret key which was simple enough.
- Step 5 involves setting an environment variable to read that secret key by pointing to the config file.

Note that this takes place using a **virtual environment**.

The instructions say to:
`set OPENAI_CONFIG=/path/to/config/openai.cfg` (for Windows users)

Despite trying this approach it doesn't seem to update OPENAI_CONFIG. I believe you can test this using `echo %OPENAI_CONFIG%`

I also tried one suggested approach for virtual environments to add $env:Path += like this:
`(GPTJay) (base) PS C:\Users\User\gpt3-sandbox\examples> $env:Path += 'C:\Users\User\gpt3-sandbox\api';`

Any help would be much appreciated! Also I am using Anaconda Powershell Prompt, not sure if that makes any difference from 'vanilla' Powershell?

Comment: If you simply want to set `OPENAI_CONFIG`, you should be able to just `$env:OPENAI_CONFIG = "some value"`.

Comment: Perfect thanks. In my case it ended up being $env:OPENAI_CONFIG = 'openai.cfg' in case anyone else has this exact issue